# Ensuring last in, last out ordering of Task.Run results

Tags: .net, async-await, task

Entering a value into a text box in my UI starts a CPU-bound task that takes a variable amount of time. Each time a new value is entered, any previously started task should be cancelled and the results discarded. The results of the most recently started task should be displayed in the UI once the task is completed. The UI should remain responsive while the task is executed in the background.

How can I achieve this using `Task.Run`?

[This implementation](http://www.bucketsoft.com/blog/post/avoiding-race-conditions-with) using `BackgroundWorker` appears to work well.

Comment: [Task Cancellation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Have a look at [Reactive Extensions (Rx)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh242985). That's what they were build for.

Comment: @PauloMorgado Thanks - using Rx (potentially combined with [ReactiveUI](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI)) should make this task straightforward. Still, I'm interested to know if there's a clean pattern for using Task.Run to manage a single background task in the same way as BackgroundWorker in the linked example.